# How can i apply CSS with Jquery at parent div on user selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can i use Jquery to add a class on user selection?

My Aspx markup is as follows.

```
     <div id="Answer" class="Ans">
           <div id ="Left"> 
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool1" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans1") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool2" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans2") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool3" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans3") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool4" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans4") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool5" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans5") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool6" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans6") %>' />
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans1Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans2Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans3Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans4Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField5" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans5Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField6" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans6Bool") %>'/>
           </div>
        </div>
```

The visitor may select the answer by choosing the "winning question" radiobutton

The HiddenFields contain true or false

So if the user selects the rdAnsBool1 and the value of the HiddenField1 is "True", the JQuery should add a "correct" CSS class to the parent div with ID = Answer

If the user selects the rdAnsBool1 and the value of the HiddenField1 is "False", the JQuery should add a "wrong" CSS class to the parent div with ID = Answer

In your answers please keep in mind that the following markup is rendered within a list view

And here is the JSFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/VTevz/

Comment: If it's a Javascript question, the serverside code is irrelevant. Include the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an FYI, hidden field values are visible with HTML inspectors so not the best place to store secret answers.

Assuming your ID's and names will stay the same (not a very good idea but nonetheless)...

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/VTevz/6/

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name$="answers"]').change(function() {
        // clear all the previous classes
        $('input[name$="answers"]').parent().removeClass('correct').removeClass('wrong');

        // get the index of the selected answer
        var i = $('input[name$="answers"]').index(this);

        // get the value of the corresponding correct answer
        var answer = $('input[type="hidden"]:eq(' + i + ')').val();

        // check if it's true and add the appropriate class
        if (answer == 'True') $(this).parent().addClass('correct');
        else $(this).parent().addClass('wrong');
    });
});
```

Comment: Remember to use <%= THE_ASPNET_ID.ClientID %> in the [name=] attribute, since the ID is not unique.

Comment: The name is not unique, however a radio *group* is selected by its name attribute, and thus the value is derived from that.

Comment: @TerryR Hello sir, i guess i am doing something terribly wrong here, since the $('#HiddenField1') value always returns "undefined".

Comment: Because it isn't rendered in HTML as "HiddenField1", it's rendered as `ctl00_Content_ListView1_ctrl0_HiddenField1`.  Use `$('input[id$="HiddenField1"]')` which means find the element with an `id` that _ends with_ "HiddenField1".